# passing session php to java script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want make jQuery / ajax for take var stored at php session here some code

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
alert("a");
requestSession("isadmin");

});

function requestSession(obj){
    var request;
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false})  ;
    $.get('php/requesSession.php',{requested : obj },function(data){
            request = data
            alert("request");
        }); 
    return request;
}
```

Then here my php script

```
<?php
if(isset($_Get['requested'])){
 print $_SESSION[$_Get['requested']]];
}else{

print json_encode($_SESSION);
}
?>
```

it doesn't work. where is my mistake ?

Comment: You should be looking at `$_GET`, which is not the same as `$_Get`

Comment: `print $_SESSION[$_GET['requested']];` instead

Answer (score 0):

Change `$_Get` to `$_GET`. Also there are an extra `]` in the line `print $_SESSION[$_Get['requested']]];`. You need to assign some vale to session variable before access it. Example:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['requested'])){
    print $_SESSION['var'] = $_GET['requested'];
}else{
    print json_encode($_SESSION);
}
```

JS:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
     //alert("a");
     requestSession("isadmin");
 });

function requestSession(obj){
    var request = '';
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false})  ;
    $.get('php/requesSession.php',{requested : obj },function(data){
        request = data
        alert(request);
    }); 
    return request;
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: i have change it bu it's didn't work

Comment: You need assign some value before accessing session. Did you add `session_start();` top of your code? Remove extra `]` from you `PHP` code as I updated!

Comment: i have done. but still didnt work

Comment: even alert request didn't show up

Comment: @FirmanPramdia I think you didn't add jQuery. Add jQuery as I updated & think it will work.